# Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that $g_1H = Hg_2$ for some $g_1,g_2 ∈ G$. Show that $g_1H = Hg_1 =g_2H =Hg_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that $g_1H = Hg_2$ for some $g_1,g_2 ∈ G$. Show that $g_1H = Hg_1 =g_2H =Hg_2$.
I have already shown that $g_1H = g_2H$. from the assumption, we have that $g_1H = Hg_2$.
To finish my proof I just need to show that $Hg_1$ is equal to one of these sets however I am stuck and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: How did you prove that $g_1H=g_2H$?

Comment: I showed that $g_1^{-1}g_2 ∈ H$ and we have a from a lemma in a textbook this is equivalent to saying $g_1H = g_2H$. I know this is cheating a bit but i couldn't find another way.

Comment: Note that $g_1H=Hg_2$ if and only if $g_2^{-1}H=Hg_1^{-1}$. So if your proof about $g_2H$ is correct, then this gives $g_2^{-1}H=g_1^{-1}H$, from which you get what you want...

Comment: Put the info in the post, not the comments.

Comment: Btw, the same argument, just changing sides, should let you prove that $Hg_1=Hg_2$ as well, from which you would get the equality you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g_1H=Hg_2$, then $g_1\in Hg_2$. Since we also have $g_1\in Hg_1$, then the cosets $Hg_1$ and $Hg_2$ are not disjoint, so they are equal.

Symmetrically, $g_2\in g_1H\cap g_2H$, so $g_1H=g_2H$.

So $g_2H=g_1H=Hg_2=Hg_1$.

Comment: Okok I completely understand your proof but that just means that gH is always equal to Hg in every single group because they both have g in common and if the two sets are not disjoint then they are equal

Comment: @user20194358 No, it doesn't mean that. Two *right* cosets are either disjoint or equal. If $g_1H=Hg_2$, then $g_1\in g_1H=Hg_2$, and $g_1\in Hg_1$. So the two **right** cosets $Hg_1$ and $Hg_2$ are not disjoint, so they are equal. The argument also works for two *left* cosets. But the property "they are either disjoint or equal" is not true if you are comparing a *right* coset and a *left* coset.

Comment: ok ok, thanks. is there a logical intuition of why we can't compare right and left cosets or is it because there exist some counter-examples?

Comment: @user20194358 For arbitrary subgroups, the two partitions are just not the same. We can compare them, but the disjunction "either equal or disjoint" is just not true.